# Create multiple charts, with multiple series, from single long format file with pandas or similar

Tags: python, pandas, plot, charts

I am trying use python and pandas with this dataset:

| LocCode | Sampled_Date-Time | ChemName | Conc_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Well 1 | 2021-03-18 | Sulfate | 660 |
| Well 1 | 2021-06-23 | Sulfate | 780 |
| Well 1 | 2021-09-14 | Sulfate | 920 |
| Well 1 | 2021-12-30 | Sulfate | 920 |
| Well 1 | 2021-03-18 | Chloride | 158 |
| Well 1 | 2021-06-23 | Chloride | 194 |
| Well 1 | 2021-09-14 | Chloride | 240 |
| Well 1 | 2021-12-30 | Chloride | 168 |
| Well 2 | 2021-03-18 | Sulfate | 990 |
| Well 2 | 2021-06-23 | Sulfate | 1170 |
| Well 2 | 2021-09-14 | Sulfate | 1380 |
| Well 2 | 2021-12-30 | Sulfate | 1380 |
| Well 2 | 2021-03-18 | Chloride | 237 |
| Well 2 | 2021-06-23 | Chloride | 291 |
| Well 2 | 2021-09-14 | Chloride | 360 |
| Well 2 | 2021-12-30 | Chloride | 252 |

To create multiple charts, like these:

[Chart 1 - Sulfate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJOAO.png)
[Chart 2 - Chloride](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtvCn.png)

So that I have:

- A single chart for each unique value in the 'ChemName' column
- With each of these charts having a series for each unique value in the 'LocCode' column
- And for each series, plot values in the 'Conc_num' column over time values in the 'Sampled_Date-Time' column

I have been trying to learn python and the pandas module to achieve this result, but am stuck. I unfortunately haven't gotten anywhere with coding anything, since everything I've watched or read so far deals with the input data in a pivoted format, on a single index.

My thought so far is that the code needs to look something like:

1. Create index that groups ChemName and LocCode
2. Iterate over this index, creating plots where x-values = Conc_num and y-values = Sampled_Date-Time

Any advice/guidance/suggestions would be greatly appreciated, or pointers to a tutorial that shows how to do this would be great too.

Thanks,

Comment: You can iterate with something like `for chemical,chem_df in df.groupby('ChemName'):` and in the loop do plotting. `chem_df` will be a pandas table with just one chemical at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you insight, you can try code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t") # You do not need this line. Just use your dataframe variable without implementing this line.
df["Sampled_Date-Time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Sampled_Date-Time"])
fig, ax =plt.subplots(len(data["ChemName"].unique()), 1, figsize=(12,8))
for index,ChemName in enumerate(data["ChemName"].unique()):
  tempDf = df[df["ChemName"] == ChemName]
  for LocCode in tempDf["LocCode"].unique():
    tempDf2 = tempDf[tempDf["LocCode"] == LocCode]
    ax[index].plot(tempDf2["Sampled_Date-Time"], tempDf2["Conc_num"])
    ax[index].scatter(tempDf2["Sampled_Date-Time"], tempDf2["Conc_num"])
  ax[index].set_title(ChemName)
  ax[index].set_xlabel("date")
  ax[index].set_ylabel("Concentration")
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
```

##### Output

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the quick response.